# Scroll the page to an <a> with a particular href with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user clicks a button, I want his browser to automatically scroll to an `<a>` with a certain href (let's call it "abc"). Ideally the scrolling would be nicely animated in some way.

Comment: Animations are distracting and get in the way of using the app.  Unless your app is an animation tool of some kind.

Comment: What if the element he's scrolling to isn't visible without scrolling?  A ScrollTo is good UX in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give a look to the [jQuery.scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin.

With that plugin you could simply:

```
$.scrollTo('a[href=abc]');
```

Answer (score 4):

Way simpler:

```
element_to_scroll_to = document.getElementById('anchorName2');
element_to_scroll_to.scrollIntoView();
```

Even no need for jQuery ;)

Comment: function scroll2()
    {
        var element_to_scroll_to = document.getElementById('address').scrollIntoView();
        
    }

Comment: but same with "a href" :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any plugin.

```
$(document.documentElement).animate({
    scrollTop: $('a#abc').offset().top
});
```